# Loading module 8192cu fails

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, modprobe

I 'm running Angstrom Linux (3.0.7) on embedded device BeagleBoard-xM. I want to load a module *(downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/embedded-geeks/downloads/detail?name=8192cu.ko&can=2&q=))* and copied into: `/lib/modules/3.0.7/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/8192cu.ko` on the BeagleBoard-xM SD card file system.

However, loading the module fails:

```
root@beagleboard:/# modprobe 8192cu                                             
FATAL: Module 8192cu not found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't think this approach will work very well. If you want a module, you need to compile it as part of the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `depmod`?  This is something `make modules_install` does automatically for you, but if you copy a module into `/lib/modules` this way, you will need to do that manually.  See `man depmod` for more information.

I am not sure if `depmod` will report the presence of incompatible modules.

You can also use an explicit path with `insmod`, which will at least test if the module can be loaded.

```
> insmod /lib/modules/3.0.7/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/8192cu.ko
> lsmod | grep 8192cu
```

If the module has dependencies, they won't be loaded, which is why `depmod` and `modprobe` make things more convenient.  Note the kernel will reject modules that do not match its version.  There is, however, a configuration option to disable this safety feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, after running `depmod`, `modprobe 8192cu` fails with: `[ 4038.569152] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
FATAL: Error inserting 8192cu (/lib/modules/3.0.7/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/8192cu.ko): Invalid module format`. Module is supposed to work with 3.0.7 kernel. Is there any way I can resolve this?

Comment: Try with `modprobe -f`.